# MVC3 Ajax.BeginForm's AjaxOptions Callbacks not being called in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

I have a very standard layout for an ajax.beginform with a callback on OnSuccess. But in IE8, the callback does not get called, but it works fine in Chrome.

I am including jquery.validate.min.js, jquery.validate.unobstusive.min.js, and jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js in my view.

The view is used as a partial view, and contains all the scripts it needs, as well as the javascript function that the callback will call.

I will also note, that I had to upgrade my jquery.validate.min.js that came with the initial creation of the MVC3 project to one that would work properly with IE8 already.

Are there any known issues with why this would not work? Or am I missing something?

[cshtml]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FormSuccess(context) {
        alert("FormSuccess()");
    };
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetMessage", "Form", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "FormSuccess" }))
{
```

[Controller]

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    return Json( success = true, message = "success" );
}
```

In Chrome, the callback is hit, but in IE8 I get a file download dialog. When the file is downloaded, I get a file containing the following:

```
{"success":false,"messages":"success"}
```

As you can see, it is a very simple thing I am doing here, but it just does not seem to want to work in IE8.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found out that because I am rendering a razor cshtml file form an ascx page, the AjaxOptions callbacks are not being called. I created a sandbox app that does the same thing, and if I have a cshtml render a partial cshtml, everything works fine, but if I have a aspx render a partial cshtml, the callbacks do not get called

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following is incorrect

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    return Json( success = true, message = "success" );
}
```

.change it to :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMessage(MessageModel model)
    {

        return new JsonResult{success = true, message = "success"};
    }
```

**EDIT:**

you have to return a complete View instead of json result.

if you want to sent ajax request and get JSON result you must send it via jquery ajax function.

Comment: This still gives me the file download dialog

Comment: I can actually not even build with the above code. Does not like the lack of the success variable

Comment: i was facing with same problem.is your page refreshing(posting)?

Comment: hey i found it.you shouldn't return json result at all.

Comment: But returning JSON works fine in Chrome, is that an IE8 issue? And I really don't want to return a view, unless I will be able to return a view and have it act like JSON so I can parse out the contents.

Comment: no it is not an ie issue.whit Ajax.BeginForm the view returned from the action will rendered without post back.but you can not return JSON result.if you post your complete view code i can help you with this.